# Property 'children' does not exist on type 'AriaCheckboxGroupProps'

Tags: react-tsx, react-aria

Currently working on some React components using [React-Aria](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/index.html). I just made 'Checkbox' and now I'm working on 'CheckboxGroup'.

I literally copied the documentation of `useCheckboxGroup()`, see documentation [here](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/useCheckboxGroup.html), and I'm getting this error: **Property 'children' does not exist on type 'AriaCheckboxGroupProps'** on the `value={state}`.

**Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Maybe I'm doing something wrong or they just didn't change the documentation ?**

Here is the code -- CheckboxGroup.tsx:

```js
import './CheckboxGroup.sass';

import { AriaCheckboxGroupProps, useCheckboxGroup } from 'react-aria';
import { useCheckboxGroupState } from 'react-stately';
import { createContext } from 'react';

let CheckboxGroupContext = createContext(null);

function CheckboxGroup(props) {
  let { children, label, description, errorMessage } = props;
  let state = useCheckboxGroupState(props);
  let { groupProps, labelProps, descriptionProps, errorMessageProps } =
    useCheckboxGroup(props, state);

  return (
    <div {...groupProps}>
      <span {...labelProps}>{label}</span>

      <CheckboxGroupContext.Provider value={state}> {/* ERROR HERE */}
        {children}
      </CheckboxGroupContext.Provider>

      {description && (
        <div {...descriptionProps} style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{description}</div>
      )}

      {errorMessage && state.isInvalid && (
        <div {...errorMessageProps} style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: 12 }}>
          {errorMessage}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default CheckboxGroup;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the component it's going to have children.

Depending on the version of React you're using, React requires children to be listed explicitly. [React Docs](https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide#updates-to-typescript-definitions).

You can either create a new interface or type, extending `AriaCheckboxGroupProps` and adding `children?: ReactNode`, or you can type your props like:

```
props: React.PropsWithChildren<AriaCheckboxGroupProps>
```

You'll need to `import React from 'react'`, or just `import PropsWithChildren` and don't use the 'React.' to do it this way.